# Accessing an array that is part of an object seems to fail

Tags: php

I have the following code snippet that doesn't do what I expect:

```
var_dump($pronunciationResults);
$alignEntries = $pronunciationResults->alignEntry;
var_dump($alignEntries);
```

Which produces for the first var_dump (I have elided out the end of the structure):

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1371 (1) {
  ["alignEntry"]=>
  array(123) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#1375 (3) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["alignType"]=>
        string(2) "OK"
      }
      ["target"]=>
      string(3) "The"
```

Followed by the output of the second var_dump

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1373 (3) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["alignType"]=>
    string(2) "OK"
  }
  ["target"]=>
  string(3) "The"
```

I have a really simple php program that works exactly as expected, and have no idea why in this case I get the first element of the array, rather than the array itself.

So the comment below by @trincot was interesting. However:

```
var_dump($pronunciationResults->children());
var_dump($pronunciationResults->children()->alignEntry);
var_dump($pronunciationResults->alignEntry->children());
```

Gives the exact same structure as I got above for each of the var_dump.

It turns out the foreach does walk the original alignEntries array, even though var_dump doesn't show it as an array.

I have no idea what is going on with var_dump

Comment: Your getting the first element of the array by doing:     $alignEntries = $pronunciationResults->alignEntry; because you're appointing to the first field of the array, which in this case is alignEntry. Was that your question?

Comment: @MiguelCruz: No, that would be `$pronunciationResults->alignEntry[0]`

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($pronunciationResults->alignEntry);` ?

Comment: It's been awhile but try `$alignEntries = $pronunciationResults->alignEntry->children()`

Comment: Don't use var_dump for SimpleXML, use - >asXML()

Answer (score 2):

Your objects are not standard objects. You should use them using the appropriate API. In case of an instance of [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php), you can get the children array via the method [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php):

```
foreach ($pronunciationResults->children() as $child) {
    var_dump($child);
}
```

Of course, since also those child elements are of the `SimpleXMLElement` class, you should also treat those via the proper methods. So if you would want to iterate over their attributes, then call the [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method on them, ...etc.

Do not focus on what you see in `var_dump`, except for the class. You'll see undocumented properties  which are not supposed to be used directly. Stick to the documented interface for those objects.

Comment: I updated the question with some results engendered from this excellent possibility.

Comment: Don't rely on undocumented properties. The class is free to return other things than you expect when you access them. See addition to answer.